# Geometrically describing a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, linear-transformations

Let A = $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. Describe the linear transformation T(x) = Ax geometrically. If a reflection, what is the plane of reflection? If a rotation, what is the axis/angle of rotation?

I'm not sure what this transformation is. Initially, I thought that since x maps to -z, y maps to x, and z maps to x-y+z that this would be a reflection over the plane x-y+z, but that doesn't seem to be the right answer. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't $x$ map to $(0, 1, 1)$, which is $y + z$?  Similarly with the other basis vectors.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I forgot that the vectors are columns. Since z maps to -x+z, wouldn't x essentially be cancelled out? Leaving z = z which means that our plane of reflection is z? @JoeJohnson126

Comment: Your matrix has determinant $1$.  A matrix representing a reflection and no other transformation has determinant $-1$.  I did not downvote you.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure what the determinant of 1 tells us in this case. Possibly a rotation? Although that doesn't seem right

Answer (score 2):

Let's see how far we can get without doing any calculations requiring working. A quick expansion along the top row shows that $\det A = 1$. By inspection, it can be seen that $v = (1, 1, -1)$ satisfies $Av = v$ and so the line spanned by $v$ is fixed under the action of $A$. The product of the three eigenvalues is the determinant $\det(A) = 1$, and the sum of the three eigenvalues is the trace $\operatorname{tr}(A) = 1$. Since we have already found that $1$ is an eigenvalue, the product of the other two eigenvalues is $1$ and their sum is $0$, therefore the other two eigenvalues are $\pm i$ and so there must be a plane which is rotated by $90^\circ$.

The plane of rotation can be found by looking at the null-space of $(A - i)(A + i) = A^2 + I$. Here we do some actual work:
$$ A^2 + I = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
This matrix has a null-space spanned by $u = (1, 0, 0)$ and $w = (0, 1, 1)$, and we can check indeed that $Au = w$ and $Aw = -u$, so $A$ indeed acts as a rotation on the plane spanned by $u$ and $w$.

Therefore $A$ acts as a rotation, fixing the axis $\mathbb{R}v$ and rotating the plane $\mathbb{R}\{u, w\}$ by $90^\circ$. As a final point, note that under the usual dot product, the axis is not perpendicular to the plane, and while $u$ and $w$ are perpendicular they do not have the same length, so we might want to call this an "algebraic" rotation, rather than a "geometric" one which we would expect to preserve lengths and angles.